# Screen height for iPhone4 with 4-inch screen

Tags: ios, iphone-5, mainscreen

I wanna update my app, that is created using iOS5 SDK, to fit iPhone5's 4-inch screen. I simulate it with iPhone5 simulator. The following code tells us that the screen height is still 480.00 but not 548. What should I do to let my app to be taller but without the black gap in the bottom of the iPhone5's 4-inch screen? Any help is appreciated:)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    float screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    NSLog(@"screenHeight :%f",screenHeight);
}
```

log:

```
2012-09-20 14:47:36.554 FF[61898:c07] screenHeight :480.000000
```

Comment: Hm, strange. I use this peace of code: CGRect frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
    NSLog(@"Width = %f", frame.size.width);
    NSLog(@"Height = %f", frame.size.height); and I get Width = 320 and Height = 568; Did you set in iOS Simulator that it uses iPhone Retina 4 Inch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is poorly documented by Apple, but it seems like you have to provide a 4-inch launch image to let iOS know that you are built to take advantage of the tall screen. Only then will you get to use the full screen.

Comment: do you know what's the name of the launch image for iPhone5? Default.png and Default@2x.png is sued.

Comment: Not offhand, but select the project to the left in Xcode and use the info editor to set the 4-inch image and it should create that image for you.

Comment: the name should be Default-568h@2x

Answer (score 0):

> > Screen size for iPhone and iPad is.
> >
> > iPhone : 
> >     Portrait :  320x460
> >       Landscape : 480x300
> >
> > iPad :
> >     Portrait : 768x1004 
> >     Landscape : 1024x748